# Arithmetic Boggle using recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am trying to solve an arithmetic boggle using python. The function `f` takes a `target` number and a list of `numbers`. It returns true if it can insert add or subtract operations in the list of numbers to get the target number. Otherwise, it returns false.

For example:

```
f(10, [1, 2]) = false. There's no way to add or subtract 1 and 2 to get 10.
f(2, [1, 2, 3, 4]) = true. 1 + 2 + 3 - 4 = 2.
f(0, []) = true
f(1, []) = false
f(1, [1]) = true
f(0, [1]) = false
```

I have the following code so far

```
def f(target, numbers):
    if len(numbers) == 0:
        if target == 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    elif len(numbers) == 1:
        if target == numbers[0]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        helper (target, numbers, 0, 0)


def helper (target, numbers, index, total):
    if index==len(numbers):
        if target == total:
            print("got it")
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        curr = total+numbers[index]
        print(index, curr)
        helper (target, numbers, index+1, curr)
        curr = total-numbers[index]
        print(index, curr)
        helper (target, numbers, index+1, curr)
```

The issue is even if it finds the match, it doesn't return `True`. That is because when it finds a match, it returns true from that stage of recursion, goes back to the caller and calls the next recursion.

How do I solve this issue? Any suggestion?

Comment: Wherever you call the helper function, you need to look at its return value, and if it is true, return that immediately. Also in f, you need to check what the helper returns, and act accordingly.

Comment: Btw, I didn't post that as an answer because I assume very similar questions have been asked before and so it will be closed as a duplicate, but I can't find a similar question with good answers right now.

Comment: @m69 probably can't find one because the solution is part of the fundamental idea of how recursion works. I don't expect this question to be something other users would find useful.